# How to See a List of ALL the fans of Your Facebook Page

Tags: facebook

I organized a giveaway on my site which required readers to like our fan page, like the post and comment on the post. The giveaway period is over and I am now trying to verify who all of the those participated have actually liked the fan page. And this is where I am facing the problem.

When I go to the fan page admin and click See All likes, it displays a long list but for some reason it does not show all the fans. There are 2025 likes that the fan page has received (i.e 2025 total fans) but it doesn't show all of them. I know that because I can't find certain people in the list which I know for a fact are fans of our page. I can even see on their profile that they like our page. But their name doesn't show up in the list.

I have tried several ways to see a list of fans. I have extracted the page id by going to http://graph.facebook.com/pagename and then used that id here - https://www.facebook.com/browse/page_fans/?page_id=XXXXXXXXX to check if there's a more elaborate list of all the fans. But each time the same list comes up, I keep scrolling down till it ends and then I do cmd+f to find certain names which I know are fans, and they are not there in the list. So basically, the list doesn't consist all the 2025 fans.

So, what I want is a way to get a list of all the 2025 fans of my Facebook page on a single page so that I can accurately verify who all completed the giveaway steps. Any way to do that folks?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This is not a programming question; Stack Overflow is only for programming questions. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: I did a little more research and found that it only shows 500 likes and some are saying that Facebook removed the ability to see all your page likes a year ago. Any way to overcome that?

Comment: David - yeah not entirely a programming question but I figured it'll likely require a script or something like that, hence posted here.

Answer (score 2):

You *should* be able to run an FQL query on page_likes to show who is a fan of your page, but Facebook removed the ability to do so.

You can easily get a list of the UIDs of your blocked users:

```
SELECT uid FROM page_blocked_users WHERE page_id=XXXXXXXXXX
```

But a similar query to find the UIDs of fans:

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id=XXXXXXXXXX
```

Returns

> (#604) Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql

The only way to find the list of all your page's fans would be to query all FB users' profiles individually and see if they are fans with your page. You'd need to be personally friends with them to make this happen.

However, you *CAN* get a list of UIDs who liked a specific post, photo or other object on your page using this FQL. You'll need to query your page's `stream` to get the `post_id`.

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE post_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```